# How to edit Azure App Configuration using C#

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a Razor Pages Web App which stores some user preference info in the Azure App Configuration. The only way I know of editing these configuration parameters is by logging into Azure Portal and go through the Configuration Explorer. I want to give the Administrators the ability to edit these values through the Razor Pages instead of the Azure Portal.
As a sample I tried with a console application as below. But I don't know how to access the `Data` count. When I added a watch I was able to expand and see the count, shown in the screenshot.
Please guide me how to access the `Data` and also the underneath array of `key:value` pairs.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration("connection string");
        var config = builder.Build();
        Console.WriteLine(config["TestApp:Settings:Message"] ?? "Hello world!");
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way to do it. Here is the working code.

```
        var config = builder.Build();
        var iconfig = (IConfiguration)config;
        var kvPairs = iconfig.GetChildren().ToList();
        Console.WriteLine($"Total configs found {kvPairs.Count}");
        var configList = (config as IConfiguration).GetChildren().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to use [Azure.Data.AppConfiguration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration/) nuget package to update it

Then you can use something like:

```
string connectionString = "<connection_string>";
var client = new ConfigurationClient(connectionString);
ConfigurationSetting setting = client.SetConfigurationSetting("some_key", "new_value");
```

More info: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/appconfiguration/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration

Comment: Yes, I am using the same samples from GitHub but I want to know how to capture the value in `DATA`